# Quiz in Tkinter, fixing if ... else loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a quiz app in Tkinter, so far I have got the code below – but even when I type in the right answer it always comes up with false.

```
import tkinter
from random import randint

score = 0

def question():
    global number1
    global number2
    number1 = randint(1,12)
    number2 = randint(1,12)
    question = tkinter.Label(window, text="What is " + str(number1) + "x" + str(number2) + " ?")
    question.pack()

def Validate():
    global score
    global number1
    global number2
    ans = number1 * number2
    if answer == number1*number2:
        score = score+1
        print('True')
    else:
        score = score-1
        print('False')

window = tkinter.Tk()
question()
answer = tkinter.Entry(window)
submit = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Submit", command=Validate)
answer.pack()
submit.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're comparing a `tkinter.Entry` to a number. Of course that'll always result in `False`.

Comment: Oh, do you know how to convert it to an integer? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rawing commented, the code is comparing `tkinter.Entry` object to an object.

You can get the text entered to Entry using `Entry.get()`, you can convert the string to `int` object using `int()`:

```
def Validate():
    global score
    answer_string = answer.get()
    try:
        answer_value = int(answer_string)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        return

    if answer_value == number1 * number2:
        score -= 1
        print('True')
    else:
        score += 1
        print('False')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, falstru.